# How to append listview items from the Internet

Tags: java, android, http, android-listview

I'm still struggling to find an answer to my question. I want to download 3 strings for each item in the listview to the phone. I know how to get all the data from the server, just not how to append the data to the litview, I'm really annoyed and this problem is dragging me down.

My Code:

```
public class ChatService extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chatservice);
        try {
            ContactsandIm();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CheckLogin();


    private void CheckLogin() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                /* login.php returns true if username and password is equal to saranga */
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://gta5news.com/login.php");

                try {

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    Log.w("HttpPost", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent())
                            .toString();
                    Log.w("HttpPost", str);

                    if (str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                        Log.w("HttpPost", "TRUE");
                        try {Thread.sleep(250);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        //put intent here(21/3/12); 

                    } else {
                        Log.w("HttpPost", "FALSE");

                    }

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
                String line = "";
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                // Read response until the end
                try {
                    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                        total.append(line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Return full string
                return total;
            }




    private void ContactsandIm() throws URISyntaxException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String data = null;


        HttpClient get = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI website = new URI("http://www.gta5news.com/test.php");
        HttpGet webget = new HttpGet();
        webget.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = get.execute(webget);
        Log.w("HttpPost", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
        in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        //now we'll return the data that the PHP set from the MySQL Database.




        if (in.equals("True")); {
            Toast.makeText(this,"yay", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }






    }

    // end bracket for "ContactsandIm"

    private void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in this code that you show that would add anything to a ListView.

Comment: That's because, I don't know how. As I said, in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `ArrayAdapter` on your list, and add items to this adapter, then call `notifyDatasetChanged` on it, and zou

Comment: Is their an android developers page, that has this method?

Answer (score 0):

First of all when we connect to Server using the Network Threads, then you should go for `AsyncTask` or `Handlers`. Which is specially used for handling such `Thread`s.

`ListView` can be created by using default Listview ans also the Custom Listview where we can design our own Row design in the Row.xml and the same design will be used for all the rows.

If you want move forward or go for some advanced Listview then even we can use 'n' number of designs for different rows.

Here in your case, You should use a AsyncTask for fetching the data and use the Listview for displaying rows.

You can get more information from the below link.

https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B2qCFbmeiTFxN2ViZjVlOTUtNmY3ZS00NThhLTg3N2UtYjVkYjgyM2Y4MWUy&hl=en&authkey=COeP8JYN

Comment: As I said, I know how to design listviews, NOT how to append data from a HttpGet.

Comment: Every Adapter we should give a Collection object or String array to pass the data. Write your custom adapter as a inner class and make the Collection object or String array global. Then after where ever you want just update the Collection object or Array list and just call adapter object.notifyDatasetChanged();. This will automatically update the new Data in to the List.